# Can't push on prop "history"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So, in my component OrganismSettings I redirect the user to another page if there is an error in the request. I tried to do that and redirect the user. However, I get the following error :
`OrganismSettings.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

This error was solved a long time ago by adding "withRouter", but this didn't fix the issue this time.
I really can't find what seems to be the issue with my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard'
import Axios from 'axios'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import ErrorContainer from '../../components/ErrorContainer'
import { addAlgolia, handleChange } from 'utils'

export class OrganismSettings extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {loading: true, organism: [], name: "", description: "", address: "", picture: null}
        this.getOrganism = this.getOrganism.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleChangePicture = this.handleChangePicture.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getOrganism();
        addAlgolia()
    }

    getOrganism() {
        Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/organism/settings', {headers: {Accept: 'application/json', Authorization: 'Bearer ' + Cookies.get('token')}})
        .then((success) => {
            var organism = success.data.data.organism;
            this.setState({organism: success.data.data.organism, loading: false})
            this.setState({name: organism.name, description: organism.description, address: organism.address})
        }, (error) => {
            this.props.history.push('/organisme/creation')
        })
    }

      handleChangePicture(event) {
        this.setState({picture: event.target.files[0]})
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', this.state.name);
        formData.append('description', this.state.description);
        formData.append('address', this.state.address);
        formData.append('picture', this.state.picture);
        formData.append('_method', 'PATCH');
        var token = Cookies.get('token');
        Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/organism/settings', formData, {
            headers: {
                "Accept": 'application/json',
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
            }
        }).then(
            (success) => {
                this.setState({loading: false});
                //this.props.history.push('/organisme')
            }, (error) => {
                this.setState({errors : error.response.data.data})
                if(error.response.data.redirect != "") {
                    this.props.history.push(error.response.data.redirect)
                }
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Dashboard loading={this.state.loading}>
                <section className="section has-text-centered">
                    <div className="column is-offset-1 is-10">
                    <h1 className="title is-size-1 register-title">Paramètres de {this.state.name}</h1>
                        <section className="section organism-register">
                            <form encType="multipart/form-data" className="user-form fullbox-form" method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <div className="has-text-left input-fixer">
                                <label className="is-size-4">Nom de l'organisme : </label><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nom de l'organisme" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                <label className="is-size-4">Description de l'organisme : </label><textarea name="description" placeholder="Description de l'organisme" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                                <label className="is-size-4">Adresse de l'organisme : </label><input id="address-input" type="text" name="address" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                                <label className="is-size-4">Ajouter le logo de votre organisme : </label>
                                <input type="file" name="picture" onChange={this.handleChangePicture} />
                                </div>
                                <ErrorContainer errors={this.state.errors} />
                                <button className="button is-primary has-text-left">Soumettre les changements</button>
                            </form>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </Dashboard>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(OrganismSettings)
```

ROUTER :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Navigation from './components/navigation/Navigation'
import HomepageHomepage from './pages/homepage/HomepageHomepage'
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard'
import NoMatch from './pages/NoMatch'
import Register from './pages/register/Register'
import RegisterVolunteer from './pages/register/RegisterVolunteer'
import RegisterOrganism from './pages/register/RegisterOrganism'
import EmailConfirmation from './pages/register/EmailConfirmation';
import EmailConfirmed from './pages/register/EmailConfirmed';
import Login from './pages/login/Login'
import DashboardHomepage from './pages/dashboard/DashboardHomepage';
import UserProfile from './pages/user/UserProfile'
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute'
import Logout from './pages/Logout'
import AddOrganism from './pages/organization/AddOrganism'
import OfferCreation from './pages/organization/OfferCreation'
import OfferPage from './pages/organization/OfferPage'
import OrganismOffers from './pages/organization/OrganismOffers'
import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component'
import OrganismOffer from './pages/organization/OrganismOffer'
import "../src/css/app.scss"
import ClassicSearch from './pages/search/ClassicSearch'
import { OrganismSettings } from './pages/organization/OrganismSettings'
import WorkingOn from './pages/WorkingOn'
import InterestsIndex from './pages/admin/interests/InterestsIndex';
import AddInterest from './pages/admin/interests/AddInterest';
import ManageInterest from './pages/admin/interests/ManageInterest'
import EditUser from './pages/user/EditUser'
import SmartSearch from './pages/search/SmartSearch'
import AlternativeDashboardHomepage from './pages/dashboard/AlternativeDashboardHomepage';
export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <ReactNotification />
          <div>
            <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/profil/modifier">
                <EditUser />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/profil">
                <UserProfile />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/tableaudebord">
                {/* <DashboardHomepage /> */}
                <AlternativeDashboardHomepage />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute reverse="true" exact path="/inscription">
                <Register />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute reverse="true" exact path="/inscription/benevole">
                <RegisterVolunteer />
              </PrivateRoute>
              <PrivateRoute reverse="true" exact path="/connexion">
                <Login />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute reverse="true" exact path="/inscription/organisme">
              <RegisterOrganism />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/recherche">
              <ClassicSearch />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/recherche-intelligente">
              <SmartSearch />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/offres/:id">
              <OfferPage />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/organisme/creation">
              <AddOrganism />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/organisme/offres/nouvelle">
              <OfferCreation />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/organisme/offres/:id">
              <OrganismOffer />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/organisme/offres">
              <OrganismOffers />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/organisme/parametres">
              <OrganismSettings />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute path="/deconnexion">
              <Logout />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/interests/:id">
              <ManageInterest />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/interests">
              <InterestsIndex />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/admin/interests/store">
              <AddInterest />
            </PrivateRoute>
            <Route exact path={['/groupes', '/dons']} component={WorkingOn} />
            <Route exact path={["/inscription/verifier-email"]} component={EmailConfirmation} />
            <Route exact path={["/inscription/email-confirme"]} component={EmailConfirmed} />
            <Route exact path={["/", "/accueil"]} component={HomepageHomepage} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

PRIVATE ROUTE :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'


export function PrivateRoute({ children, reverse = false, ...rest }) {
    if(reverse) {
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({ location }) =>
            (Cookies.get('token') == undefined) ? (
                children
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                to={{
                    pathname: "/tableaudebord",
                    state: { from: location }
                }}
                />
            )
            }
        />
        );
    }
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={({ location }) =>
          (Cookies.get('token') != undefined) ? (
            children
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/connexion",
                state: { from: location }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }

export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: did you checked if you're getting `history` object in `props` ?

Comment: weirdly enough, the props seem empty...

Comment: did you rendered `OrganismSettings` under any router? If not you cannot use `withRouter` outside the `Router`

Comment: yes, under the same router as all my other pages (and it works on the other pages though)

Comment: Can you also provide the router component's code?

Comment: I just edited to add the Router and PrivateRoute code.

Comment: Other than the *inconsistent* use of `component` and just wrapping pages as children within your `Route`s nothing stands out as odd here. Are you sure *all* other pages are all receiving `location`, `match`, and `history` props`? There're three `history.push` calls in the `OrganismSettings`, do you know which is the issue? Line 33 doesn't help us much here where we've not the line numbers to match anything up. The one in `getOrganism` in the "error" branch? Have you dropped a debugger or `console.log(this.props)` just before it to check?

Comment: Are you sure you have initialised the history object and passed into the outermost router with something like `createBrowserHistory()`? :o

Comment: So, I checked and noticed that OrganismSettings doesn't receive the props location, match and history. All the other pages (with "withRouter"), received them. I don't get why this particular page doesn't.